# How to get x and y coordinate value with vertical and horizontal line marking the touch value with tooltip in react-native-svg-charts

Tags: react-native, d3.js, expo, react-native-svg, react-native-svg-charts

How to get x and y coordinate value with vertical and horizontal line marking the touch value with tooltip in react-native-svg-charts.

I just want to make same as given here in this link with react-native-svg-charts

https://github.com/FormidableLabs/victory-native/issues/358#issuecomment-411775865

Comment: listen for touch event on your svg

Comment: @CoderinoJavarino can you tell the the simple code how to make it. As I am very new to this so I don't know how to code it

Comment: @RajatVerma Have you found any solution on this? I am also struggling  with this.